# Why is the "Peek Top Bar on Fullscreen" GNOME extension not working?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I recently re-installed Ubuntu 23.10.1 and wanted to re-install the GNOME extension [Peek Top Bar on Fullscreen](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6048/peek-top-bar-on-fullscreen/). I installed `gnome-browser-connector`, then opened the page and enabled the extension. When asked if I would like to install the extension, I confirmed.

In the extensions menu, I also ensured that extensions as a whole, as well as this specific extension, were enabled as can be seen in my screenshot:

[image: The extension Peek top Bar on Fullscreen is enabled]

However, when I run any application in fullscreen, be it a video in Chrome or a game, it no longer displays the top bar on my second monitor, as it did in my previous installation. It's not a matter of "this app is just not supported", because it worked *just fine* before I re-installed Ubuntu. I can not for the life of me figure out why all of a sudden the extension wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: There may be some issues with this extension as outlined in the Comments section of Extensions. It is suggested that issues with ot should be directed at https://github.com/marcinjahn/gnome-peek-top-bar-on-fullscreen-extension/issues

Comment: This is a workaround rather than an answer, but [Fullscreen Avoider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4362/fullscreen-avoider/) works on 23.10.1.

Comment: did you report the issue to the developer as suggested?

Comment: @graham Yes, I've made a new github issue. I'll try to support the developer as best as I can

Comment: brilliant... good to know 